программа находит делитель, который является простым числом, но простое число не является наибольшим (т.е есть простое больше) как это исправить?
local n = 600851475143
local sqrt_n = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
local p = 1   

  while (p <= sqrt_n) do
local q = n  
  for i = p + 1, sqrt_n do
     if (n % i == 0) then
        q = i
        break
     end
  end
        p = q


     while (n % p == 0) do
         n = n // p
     end

         sqrt_n = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
     end

         print(p)


13195-ю, код не выдает максимальное. С 13195 он выдает простое 13, а максимальное 29. А с числом, что в коде (600 миллиардов), тоже самое происходит.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1596827/416121: здесь вы найдёте исправленный код, который всегда печатает максимальный простой делитель числа.

А в чем разница расположения вычисления корня. Почему в предыдущем варианте кода, считалось не до конца?

Слишком жёсткое условие во внешнем while. Я его ослабил, теперь цикл иногда делает на одну итерацию больше и всегда возвращает последнее, самое большое, простое число. Код заодно стал короче и проще.

И еще вопрос, почему действие второго цикла while нельзя засунуть в if? Просто если проследить логику программы, то это мне кажется возможным? Или я что-то упускаю?
И еще я только начинаю вникать в логику компьютера, поэтому второй вопрос. Я так понял, что если в цикле if число изначально разделилось на 2, то оно продолжит делиться и дальше пока не появиться число, которое не делиться на 2 и тогда как я понял цикл переходит на деление на 3?

if не сработает для последнего простого делителя. Поэтому while туда я не помещаю. Да, вы поняли правильно. Из n вычищаются сперва 2, потом 3 и так далее. Вам будет проще если вы добавите в код отладочную печать или пройдёте код в отладчике.

Если скажите как запустить отладчик, буду премного благодарен! Я работаю в Visual Studio Code.

https://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+code+lua+debugger
